# Absolute value of $f$ is bounded by Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to figure out why for a Lebesgue measurable function $f$, $|f(b)| \leq f^* (b)$ for almost all $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Here, $f^*(x)$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. That is
$f^*(b) = \sup _{t>0} \frac{1}{2 t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t}|f|$. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. For a bit of context... I am self teaching myself Measure theory using Axler's book. This question has really stumped me.

Comment: That follows from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) i suppose

Comment: show that for every $a>0$ the measure of the points where $|f(b)| \ge f^* (b) +a$ is zero since otherwise, you can get a small interval where $|f(b)| \ge f^* (b) +a/2$ mostly while $|f(b)|$ is not too big on a set of very small measure inside the interval and that contradicts the inequality etc; then write the set you want as a countable union for some $a_n \to 0$

Comment: Sorry, i'm still not getting anywhere with that. Can you elaborate please?